# security and google id

Tags: google-account, security, authentication

There are lots of apps (on my phone, on the web, etc.) that want to use my google id for authentication and to sync data -- news readers, contact info, notes to google docs, etc. In general, they ask for your google uid and password directly, which seems like a huge security hole to me -- I basically have to trust each app developer with my email login. I'm currently using a secondary gmail address for this sort of thing, but that can be inconvenient.

- Is there some way to restrict the kind of access that I give the apps?
- Assuming I'm not missing something, what's the best place in the google universe to post a feature request for better control over this stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current defacto solution for this problem is [OAuth](http://oauth.net), which Google supports. Applications using OAuth don't need your google ID and password to get authorization from Google to access your data.

- http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuthForInstalledApps.html

I'd suggest to the app developers in question to migrate to OAuth.

Comment: These days, developers using an authentication method requiring users to enter their passwords directly into a third-party application or website are a diminishing minority. The user should never have to trust a third-party developer with a password for another service.